# block user to provision resources not in standard region (AWS)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-iam, region

I want to know any possibility to avoid users to provision any resources in all AWS regions, except one for example ap-southeast-1.

I want nobody can provision any resources in all the AWS regions, only one region which is ap-southeast-1.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can create an IAM policy and attach it to users whose regions you want to restrict.

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [{
    "Effect": "Deny",
    "Action": "*",
    "Resource": "*",
    "Condition": {
      "StringNotEquals": {
        "aws:RequestedRegion": [
          "ap-southeast-1"
        ]
      }
    }
  }]
}
```

This policy will restrict access to `ap-southeast-1` only.

Comment: thanks for your answer Atul. Is it possible to put this policy globally so it will be applicable for all users, something like SCP. 
So not necessary to assign the policy to each users.

Comment: You can create a Group and tag this policy to the group and move all users to that group.  Now you don't need to control individual users.

Comment: thats great Atul. is there any other way to restrict to another region apart from using IAM policy?